# How to copy folder from parent into current directory for Dockerfile using Makefile

Tags: docker, makefile

I have a makefile that looks like this:

```
push:
    docker build -t dataengineering/dataloader .
    docker tag dataengineering/dataloader:latest 127579856528.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest
    docker push 127579856528.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest

deploy:
    @if [ ! "$(environment)" ]; then echo "environment must be defined"  && exit 1; fi
    @if [ ! "$(target)" ]; then echo "target must be defined"  && exit 1; fi
    kubectl delete deploy dataloader-$(target) -n dataengineering|| continue
    kubectl apply -f kube/$(environment)/deployment-$(target).yaml -n dataengineering
```

But I need a folder inside the dataloader in order for my dockerfile to actually work.

Does this work?

```
push:
    cd ..; cp -r datastore/ dataloader/
    docker build -t dataengineering/dataloader .
    docker tag dataengineering/dataloader:latest 1111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest
    docker push 11111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest

deploy:
    @if [ ! "$(environment)" ]; then echo "environment must be defined"  && exit 1; fi
    @if [ ! "$(target)" ]; then echo "target must be defined"  && exit 1; fi
    kubectl delete deploy dataloader-$(target) -n dataengineering|| continue
    kubectl apply -f kube/$(environment)/deployment-$(target).yaml -n dataengineering
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /var/dataloader

COPY assertions/ ./assertions/
...
COPY datastore/ ./datastore/

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "dataloader.py"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to copy the directory into the current directory (which would server as your Docker context), you can use `cp -r ../datastore/ dataloader/`. Unless you want the `dataloader` directory to be in the same directory as the `datastore` directory, then you'd do `cp -r ../datastore/ ../dataloader/`.